# Getting variable from results array, why can I not get more then 1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, foreach

Ok my problem is the following, basically what I am trying to do is to build href and also place the category topic name into `<h2>...</h2>` so far I can only place the Category Name by using a `$key` variable but cannot do the same with the my other variable such as `$category_topic['category_folder']` or `$category_topic['category_page']`.

Need some help please!

```
while ($category_topic = $resc -> fetch()){ 
    $result[$category_topic['category_name']][] = $category_topic;
}
foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "and", $key);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$category_topic['category_folder'].DS.$category_topic['category_page'];
print <<<END
<div class="by_cat">
<h2 class="h_unln"><a class="more_templ" href="$category_topic_url">$category_topic_name</a></h2>
<ul class="cat_tmp_list">
END;
```

after adding `print_r($category_topic);` I am getting the following

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_name] => Category Name
                    [0] => Category Name
                    [category_folder] => Category Folder
                    [1] => Category Folder
                    [category_page] => Category Page
                    [2] => Category Page
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category_name] => Category Name
                    [0] => Category Name
                    [category_folder] => Category Folder
                    [1] => Category Folder
                    [category_page] => Category Page
                    [2] => Category Page
                )
         )
  )
```

but how to write the results into variables I have no idea.

Please, please, please help.

Comment: let print_r($category_topic) in your while-loop

Comment: Umm,add this as a link $category_name[2]

Comment: @Mihai, where and how should I add it, can you please explain?

Comment: @AlexB Just clone the heredoc with $category_topic[2] instead of $category_topic_name

Comment: @Mihai I have added, works but in a very weird way, so now the Label  of the first Loop became a Label of of the second that appears after, then second is on third and so on, the very first one is coming back empty for some reason? Any idea why this is happened?

Comment: @AlexB My php is shaky at best,that was a wild guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have figured it all out now and here is my answer.

In my first approach I was only accessing the first array value (object) of which was another array. So to access that second array "sub array" I have added another `foreach`, so my entire statement looks like the following now and most importantly everything works.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $k2 => $v2){
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "and", $v2['category_name']);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$v2['category_folder'].DS.$v2['category_page'];
    }
print <<<END
<div class="by_cat">
<h2 class="h_unln"><a class="more_templ" href="{$category_topic_url}">{$category_topic_name}</a></h2>
<ul class="cat_tmp_list">
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looking at `$category_topic`, this is the name that you gave in the while loop. There for that variable will be equal to the last iteration of that loop.

Your foreach loop should look like this:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "and", $key);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$value['category_folder'].DS.$value['category_page'];
print <<<END
<div class="by_cat">
<h2 class="h_unln"><a class="more_templ" href="{$category_topic_url}">{$category_topic_name}</a></h2>
<ul class="cat_tmp_list">
END;
```

Notice how I've changed $categoryValue to $value because in your foreach loop you are assigning each iteration to $key=>$value, so that array is stored in `$value` for each loop

ie if you'd said `foreach ($result as $foo => $bar)` you would be using `$bar`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that both values in $category_topic_url are coming back empty, have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, completely missed that...you needed to wrap you variables in `{}` with heredoc.

Comment: DS is forward slash "/" and DST is Destination Directory like this "folder/"

Comment: Nope, still does not do anything, do you want to see the page may be?

Comment: I have spend entire day dealing with it, nothing seem to work, running out of options

Comment: Yeah, sure I'll have a look. Also, are there any errors being outputted in your logs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42711/discussion-between-alexb-and-ross-wilson)

Comment: Make sure you've change the url variable to the one used in my answer :)